# lines,borders,hrs when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, border

I've got to produce a print out of our records as per Creative's requirements. The layout is fairly simple, but it still makes use of the occasional highlight box and hairline ruler to divide up sections.

We have to support IE8, but for now, I'm developing in FF.

1. I currently have to go into Print Preview to examine my changes. It is a real pain to Close Preview, refresh the page with F5, then Alt-F+v to re-Preview every time I make the smallest change. Any way I can set my system up to view my changes more conveniently? I've got ReCSS, which is cool, but it does not work in Preview mode.
2. The only borders that seem to be supported are those around tables. So anywhere I need some element boxed, I end up wrapping it in `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` just to take advantage of the table border, which seems to be non-optional. Is there a more efficient way?
3. I need to divide content sections with horizontal rules (ideally several pixels thick, dashed or dotted). I have found no way to make a horizontal rule at all. I've tried styling my divs with border-bottom, which of course doesn't work. I've tried wrapping them in tables, then turning off the top left and right borders, which also doesn't work. I've tried `<hr>`, which also doesn't work. Ideas?

I hate to have to tell my Creative that they get text-with-a-side-of-text.

Comment: Why don't you post the HTML/CSS for a typical record set and perhaps a screenshot of what the designers are wishing to see.

Comment: I don't get #2 and #3. You can put borders around everything, and `<hr>` also works. Unless you make their colours white. Or wait, is Creative a piece of software, that outputs HTML, and that you hardly have any control over?